# ng-views only work through web server?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple test app that uses ng-view. It works perfectly whey I access 
it through a web server. However, when I try to open the main page 
from my local drive the views appear to stop working. I suspect that the path to 
the views cannot be found and therefore cannot display, however when using $location to 
confirm the path, it seems to be correct.

Other data bindings are working on the page, so Angular seems to be loading and running
correctly.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {


    $routeProvider
        .when("/item/:Id",
            {
                templateUrl: "partials/itemdetail.html",
                controller: "itemController"
            })
        .when("/items",
            {
                templateUrl: "partials/items.html",
                controller: "itemsController"
            })
        .when("/",
            {
                templateUrl: "partials/items.html",
                controller: "itemsController"
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });


});
```

HTML:

```
 <html data-ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/application.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body data-ng-controller="itemsController">
        <img src="{{Logo}}" width="300" />
        </br>
        <div data-ng-view></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you opening through localhost or a file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a file directly in your browser causes it to have no domain. As a result, trying to retrieve files via AJAX (such as your templates) results in a domain security exception. Trying running a local server in your directory.

If you're on a mac, open terminal, navigate to your directory and type:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```